# create uber-jar from multi module project

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I've been trying to create uber jar, that contains all my modules in the project.
I've been reading that it needs some plugins (shade/assembly) but those result in nothing build or pom-shade.

how can I create a jar from multimodule project? I want to upload it to nexus, as available dependency for other projects, but I only want one dependency that has inside every module, and not one dependency per module.

Comment: yes you can, just the uber jar is not created on the parent. make one of your modules depend on the other ones and create the uber jar there (in the last module so to say). The shade plugin is a good place to start. also if your'e using spring there is spring-boot which has an own maven-plugin to bundle itself into an uber jar (which I would consider as simpler solution than working with the shade plugin)

Comment: Make a separate project in your multi-module project and add the needed dependencies to this module and configure their maven-shade-plugin/maven-assembly-plugin to create this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, the problem with plugins was that I was using plugins on parent module. Should have used it on final module, istead of parent pom.

to put it simply: assembly opens jar, puts dependency, closes jar. I had not jar to open in parent, so...

Comment: Be careful with maven-assembly plugin if you are using spring (spring-beans, spring-context, spring-jdbc etc). Assembly plugin actually unpacks the module jars into classes and put these classes in the uber-jar. (see: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies). The result is that it will overwrite any configuration files that are common in jars.